# Issue with Time and ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, time

I'm currently working on an Appointment system and building it with Ruby on Rails. I have an Appointment model and appointments controller where on the index, I want to show a list of appointments for that day, separated by 30 minute chunks.

I have a basic working version and I've got a ruby method that adds a class on the table row which shows the if the current 30 minute chunk is the current time or not.

The issue is, it sets the row class as "current_time" when the time is anywhere between the start and end of the hour which isn't what I want.

```
def date_class(time)
    now = DateTime.now.utc

    if (now.beginning_of_hour..(now.end_of_hour - 0.5.hours)).cover?(time)
        "current_time"
    elsif ((now.beginning_of_hour + 0.5.hours)..now.end_of_hour).cover?(time)
        "current_time"
    elsif (now.beginning_of_day..now.end_of_hour).cover?(time)
        "past"
    else
        "future"
    end
end
```

Any ideas?

The screenshot below and shows that the code works fine and shows true or false correctly.

http://s.deanpcmad.com/2014/uifGf.png

Comment: Your `if` and first `elsif` is basically saying `(now.beginning_of_hour..now.end_of_hour).cover?(time)`.  What is `current_time` supposed to be?

Comment: Updated the question more with a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
def date_class(time)
    now = DateTime.now.utc
    return "past" if time < now.beginning_of_hour
    return "current_time" if now.hour == time.hour && now.min < 30 && time.min < 30 
    return "current_time" if now.hour == time.hour && now.min >= 30 && time.min >= 30 
    return "future"
end
```

I am sure there is a better way, but this would also work I think

Comment: That looks much cleaner than mine although it's still checking hours. The index shows a table with rows split 30 minutes each so it needs to show the "current_time" class only on that 30 minute row

Comment: @DeanPerry: See my edit. Make sure that the time you pass in is in UTC

Answer (score 2):

Although it has only been tested with instances of class Time for now, the [time_frame](https://github.com/injixo/time_frame) gem could be an alternative solution for this kind of problem:

```
require 'time_frame'

def date_class(time)
  now = Time.now.utc
  frame = TimeFrame.new(min: now.beginning_of_hour, duration: 29.minutes + 59.seconds)
  frame = frame.shift_by(30.minutes) if now.min >= 30
  return 'past' if frame.deviation_of(time) < 0.minutes
  return 'current_time' if frame.cover?(time)
  'future'
end

# Demo: Building 30.minutes interval blocks and print out the date class used by each block:
frame = TimeFrame.new(
  min: (Time.now.utc - 2.hours).beginning_of_hour,
  max: (Time.now.utc + 2.hours).beginning_of_hour
)
frame.split_by_interval(30.minutes).each do |interval|
  puts "#{interval.min} -> #{date_class(interval.min)}"
end
```